# Geting Python module for sybase DB connection

Tags: python, sybase

We have sybpydb module with AIM configuration. However we need to use pyodbc module for DB connection as sybpydb is not available in [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/)

Can someone advise how can I configure sypydb in our system. We are running in 3.6.x package.

Comment: did you try sqlalchemy ?

Comment: for now pyodbc been worked and we found the way around. Thanks

Comment: great you found it !